# What do this ldconfig statment into this bash script?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sh, dynamic-linking

I am pretty new in Linux and I have some doubt related to this operation that I have found into a bash script on which I am working:

```
ldconfig -v >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Reading on the man page of the ldconfig command I can read:

> ldconfig  creates,  updates,  and removes the necessary links and
>   cache
>          (for use by the run-time linker,  ld.so)  to  the  most  recent  shared
>          libraries  found  in  the directories specified on the command line, in
>          the file /etc/ld.so.conf, and in the trusted directories (/usr/lib  and
>          /lib).

What exactly mean? I am using Ubuntu system and in **/etc/ld.so.conf** I found:

```
 include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
```

So I think that this line redirect me to all the **.conf files** into **/etc/ld.so.conf.d/** directory

But I have some confusion...and many doubts:

1) What are contains into the .conf file?

2) what exactly do the command that is in my bash script?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: I think the man page answers all your questions. You might additionally read the man page of `ld`. what additional information do you need?

Answer (score 2):

`ldconfig -v >> /dev/null 2>&1` means redirect stdout (standard output) and stderr (standard error) to a special device `/dev/null` which means no-where (to discard it).

- `> /dev/null` - is redirecting stdout
- `2 > &1` is redirecting stderr to wherever stdout is redirected at since 1 is file descriptor of stdout and 2 is file descriptor of stderr

**About ldconfig:** [ldconfig man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig)

As per manual:

> `ldconfig creates the necessary links and cache to the most recent shared libraries found in the directories specified on the command line`

Comment: You are only explaining the redirection part. I guess OP is more interested in the `ldconfig` part

Comment: Oh sorry if I misunderstood that part. Have added some info and link for `ldconfig`.

Comment: Your Script seems to be importing all library files configurations
but question is why you do such thing

you ldconfig -v which will update the library database (which you can say linker) and give it to you

Answer (score 2):

> 1) What are contains into the .conf file?

`ldconfig` uses configuration scripts (which can be stacked using the `include` directive) to know which directories it should search for libraries.

from `man ldconfig`:

```
/etc/ld.so.conf     File containing a list of colon, space, tab, newline, or
                    comma-separated directories in which to search for libraries.
```

> 2) what exactly do the command that is in my bash script?

it updates the dynamic linker cache. that is: if you are installing shared libraries it will make the newly installed libraries availabled to your system.
(e.g. when installing `libfoo.so.2.1` it will create the necessary symlinks to `libfoo.so.2`)